# Keyword not supported: 'provider'. Opening SqlConnection

Tags: c#, asp.net

I don't know why this error, I tried everything. I want to connect my webForm to the Database .accdb
and when I use using(){} I got this error "Keyword not supported: 'provider"
Here is the code:

**web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString"
    connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Manuel_2\Documents\Login.accdb"     
    providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**WebForm1**

```
private static string conDB =        
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;    

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connDB))  //here is the error
   {
       // .....                            
   }              
}
```

Comment: Is it a typo or do you have really that > between Data and Source?

Comment: You can't use an OleDB connection string with SqlConnection.

Comment: @steve it's a bad type, I saw a video of kudvenkat that uses that

Comment: @manuel.koliqi you have your answer. The comment from Slaks is right

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Aleksey Mynkov has it right. But here is more detail since you are needing more clarification.

Your web.config is fine. The auto-generated Visual Studios connection string is using the right setup. Instead, on your webform1 file you need to do 2 things.

1. Add `using System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection;` to the top of your file, and remove the `using System.Data.SqlConnection;`
2. Change your webform1 code to be:

   ```
    private static string conDB = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conDB))  //here is the error
        {
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: does not recognise the using OleDB

Comment: now it's working I used only using System.Data.OleDb and changed the SqlConnection. Thank you all

Comment: @manuel.koliqi Don't forget to choose an accepted answer and up votes on all your solved questions. Welcome to Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 12):

I know this is somewhat an old thread and already answered but i'm adding my solution for future reference

I have SQL server 11.0 database, and i encountered the error when i was trying to work with it in SharePoint app, I haven't tried the other proposed answers, but i simply just deleted the "Provider" portion (and reordered) , so my connection string which looked like this:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=DBPassword;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=DBName;Data Source=DBServer
```

Now looks like this:

```
Data Source=DBServer;Initial Catalog=DBName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=DBPassword;
```

And it worked just fine

Comment: Thank you, I just deleted the Provider bit and it worked fine

Comment: you my friend are most welcome, glad to know i helped

Answer (score 5):

You should use `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection`.

Comment: the <connectionStrings> generated visual studio itself when I added the source on the gridview

Comment: @manuel.koliqi Change the `using` statement to use `OleDbConnection` is what everyone is talking about. Not the connection string.

Comment: does not recognise it, it says is a type not a namespace

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in question here (and similar) while working in Visual Studio and passing the Connection Manager name as a parameter to the Script Task to determine its connection string. Using the `ConnectionString` method brings a connection string with more elements (or value/pairs) than expected (including *provider*). The expected connection string, in my case, required only *Data Source*, *Initial Catalog*, and *Integrated Security*.

There are two options I found to solve this issue. The first, which didn't really work for me but hope it works for you, was to do the following:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(Dts.Connections[connMgrName].ConnectionString);
string connectionString = builder.DataSource + ";" + builder.InitialCatalog + ";" + builder.IntegratedSecurity;
```

I hope the above works for you because you solve the issue in a couple lines of code. However, the option that worked for me was to recreate my connection string by only selecting the value/pairs that the database needed:

```
string connectionString = Dts.Connections[connMgrName].ConnectionString;    //  ConnectionString will contain unsupported keywords like 'provider'
connectionString = connectionString.Trim(';'); //  Remove the trailing semicolon so that when we perform the split in the following line, there are no index errors.
var connStrDictionary = connectionString.Split(';').Select(x => x.Split('=')).ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);     //   Here we get each value-pair from connection string by splitting by ';', then splitting each element by '=' and adding the pair to a Dictionary.
try
{
    connectionString = "Data Source=" + connStrDictionary["Data Source"] + ";Initial Catalog=" + connStrDictionary["Initial Catalog"] + ";Integrated Security=" + connStrDictionary["Integrated Security"]; //  Build the actual connection string to be used.
}
catch(KeyNotFoundException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\t\tNot able to build the connection string due to invalid keyword used. Existing keywords and their values:");
    foreach( KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in connStrDictionary)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t\tKey = '{0}', Value = '{1}'", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I know this is pretty old, and I know that the answer was right in front of my face the whole time, but I'd like to emphasize that the one parameter that was messing me up because it was missing was`providerName="System.Data.OleDb"`. Just in case anyone else looking at this is as obtuse as I am.